# Download contents of all open pull requests on Github

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Is there a way to download the contents of all open pull requests in a given Github repository as separate markdown/text files?

I am a TA, and our current practice is to have all students submit pull requests that contain their test answers. Currently, my process is to click on each pull request, copy the raw text into a markdown file, and manually write in the points received for each question. Hoping to streamline this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the GitHub API to list, download, then view the contents of all the files.  It'll take some scripting magic, but you can [get a list of all pull requests](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests) then [download each request](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#get-a-single-pull-request) and store the contents of each pull request in a folder (say...  "C:\Class\ProjectName").